# Firebase Api key not valid Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

Estoy creando mi primer proyector de Angular y Firebase sobre autenticacion, y a la hora de registrar a un usuario me salta el siguiente error en el browser de chrome

"t {code: "auth/internal-error", message: "{"error":{"code":400,"message":"API key not valid.…son":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}", a: null}"

Tiene que ver con alguna variable, pero he buscado por internet y sus soluciones a mi no me sirven

Adjunto el archivo envrionment.ts y el app.module.ts

Envrionment.ts ->

> export const environment = {
> production: false,
> firebaseConfig : {
> apiKey: "AIzaSyDOCAbC123dEf456GhI789jKl01-MnO",
> authDomain: "myapp-project-123.firebaseapp.com",
> databaseURL: "https://myapp-project-123.firebaseio.com",
> projectId: "myapp-project-123",
> storageBucket: "myapp-project-123.appspot.com",
> messagingSenderId: "65211879809",
> appId: "1:65211879909:web:3ae38ef1cdcb2e01fe5f0c",
> measurementId: "G-8GSGZQ44ST"
> },

};

app.module.ts ->

> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; import { BrowserModule }
> from '@angular/platform-browser'; import { AppRoutingModule } from
> './app-routing.module'; import { AppComponent } from
> './app.component'; import { ReactiveFormsModule } from
> '@angular/forms'; import{ AngularFireAuthModule } from
> '@angular/fire/auth'; import{ AngularFireModule } from
> '@angular/fire'; import { environment } from
> 'src/environments/environment';
>
> @NgModule({   declarations: [
> AppComponent   ],   imports: [
> BrowserModule,
> AppRoutingModule,
> ReactiveFormsModule,
> AngularFireAuthModule,
> AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
> AngularFireAuthModule,
>
> ],   providers: [],   bootstrap: [AppComponent] }) export class
> AppModule { }

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir a la consola de Firebase, clickear en tu proyecto, ir a la seccion de Authentication y el submenu Sign-In-Method, habilita "Correo electrónico/contraseña".

Tambien te recomiendo que no compartas publicamente los datos de tu Environment!

Saludos!